# "Bind" [Key Press] with [Click]

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I have an email form submitter and i want to make it onEnter submittable (not just click)

Here is my code for the button

```
submitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitForm);
function submitForm(e:Event) {
///do stuff
}
```

Here is the code for the text field

```
emailAddress.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);
function handler(event:KeyboardEvent){
   if(event.charCode == 13){
       //submitForm() < this doesn't work (Expected 1)
   }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
emailAddress.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN,handler);

function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
 if(event.charCode == 13)
 {
     submitForm(null)
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
submitBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submitForm);
emailAddress.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, handler);

function submitForm(e:MouseEvent=null)
{
     ///do stuff
};

function handler(event:KeyboardEvent)
{
   if(event.charCode == 13) submitForm();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The function submitForm(); expects 1 parameter to be passed which is an event type variable:
 function submitForm(***e:Event***)

Therefore you need to set a default value in case the parameter is not passed:
function submitForm(***e:MouseEvent=null***)

Comment: Thanks for explaining! That seems to work as well and is 'global' too